# Is there any way to use databricks work flow parameters in Delta live table source?

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql, delta-live-tables, databricks-workflows

I am trying to create a parameterized source path for streaming table. But I am not able to do so.

I am passing year, month, day, hour parameters from job to notebook.

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING TABLE raw_saas_feature_usage_test1
AS
SELECT
*
FROM cloud_files('/mnt/Devdatalakeg2/Experiments/{{param_year}}/{{param_month}}/{{param_day}}/{{param_hour}}/Features/','csv');
```

Error is:
ExtendedAnalysisException: Unable to process statement for Table 'raw_saas_feature_usage_test1'.